# How does Versatile Weapon work like Magic Weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

[Versatile Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/versatile-weapon/) says it

> functions like [Greater Magic Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-weapon/)

I can't see the similarity between the two spells that justifies saying this, unless Versatile Weapon also adds a +1 enhancement bonus to the weapon. All of the spell duration, components, etc. are duplicated in the description of Versatile Weapon anyway, so what's the point in including this phrase in the description?

Comment: You could add tags lilke magic-weapons ans statistics.

Answer (score 4):

It is an upgraded version of Greater Magic Weapon that also allows the weapon to bypass damage reduction of a chosen type.

From the spell description:

> This spell functions like greater magic weapon, except that it subtly
>   alters the physical properties of a weapon, enabling it to bypass
>   damage reduction of one the following types: bludgeoning, cold iron,
>   piercing, silver, or slashing.

The drawback being that it only lasts minutes instead of the hours that Greater Magic Weapon lasts.